# How to handle global errors before/during app start within Aurelia / Bluebird promise

Tags: error-handling, promise, aurelia, bluebird, raygun.io

I'm adding Raygun error handling to my Aurelia application and just realized that I'm not able to catch errors which occur during app setup (e.g. within `main.configure`).

Here's the code which is not using Raygun at all but simply tries to catch all errors:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>

<body aurelia-app="main">
<script src="build/res/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror = function() {
        console.info('arguments:', arguments);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.ts**

```
// ...
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .feature('resources');

    // ...

    blah.this = 3; // <-- Force some error...
}
```

The error is logged in the console but the `onerror` handler in my index file is not called. Also Aurelias internal `ConsoleAppender.Error` is not called since I guess its not configured/activated at this stage.

Following the stack trace in the dev tools leads me to this code...

```
function tryCatcher() {
    try {
        var target = tryCatchTarget;
        tryCatchTarget = null;
        return target.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch (e) {
        errorObj.e = e;
        return errorObj;
    }
}
```

... which I guess comes from `Bluebird`...

How can I reliably catch all errors in my app?

---

Here's a screenshot of the logged error:

[image]

- `vendor-bundle.js:3411` leads to the `tryCatcher` mentioned above
- `app-bundle.js:72:9` (1st entry in stacktrace) leads to the actual error line `blah.this = 3`
- Bluebirds `unhandledRejection` & `rejectionHandled` [events](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html#global-rejection-events) are not fired in this scenario...

Comment: How is it logged in the console, as an "unhandled *rejection*"?

Comment: @Bergi I've added a screenshot of the logged error. It's not logged as an unhandled rejection. I've already tried to catch bluebirds `unhandledRejection` and `rejectionHandled` [events](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html#global-rejection-events) which are not fired in my scenario above.

Comment: Hm, weird. Maybe you need to set up the `window.onerror` handler before loading the bundle?

Comment: Moving the script which sets up the `onerror` handler before the bundle loader doesn't work either. I've also checked that the `onerror` handler is actually installed before the error occurs.